# pgfplots surface not interpolating with neighbors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3d

I am attempting to plot a relatively non-standard surface using pgfplots. The function is declared correctly, and when I create a scatter plot, everything looks as it should (note that this angle in the attached image is looking along the y-dimension so appears 2d). However, when I attempt to convert this to a surface plot, some strange behavior arises where distant points along the x-dimension attempt to interpolate together (see the second image). How can I resolve this such that points only interpolate with their neighbors?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{declare function={
        fp1(\x)= 0.3 + 9 * (\x-0.25)^2;
        fp2(\x) = 10 * (\x - 1)^4 + 0.23750000000000004;
        fdd(\x) = (\x < 0.5)?(fp1(\x)):(fp2(\x));
        checkx(\x, \y) = (\x + \y > 1)?(1 - \x):(\x);
        checky(\x, \y) = (\x + \y > 1)?(1 - \y):(\y);
        triz(\x, \y) = checkx(\x, \y) + 0.5 * checky(\x, \y);}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[view={0}{0}]
        \addplot3 [scatter,only marks, samples = 20, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:1, z buffer=sort] ({triz(x,y)},{checky(x,y)},{fdd(triz(x,y))});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[view={0}{0}]
          \addplot3 [surf, shader = interp, mesh/ordering=x varies, samples = 20, domain = 0:1, y domain = 0:1, z buffer=sort] ({triz(x,y)},{checky(x,y)},{fdd(triz(x,y))});
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: pgfplots is not, per se, prepared to plot surfaces in which the functions jump. It tries to connect images of coordinates close to each other, but because of the step functions involved the images are far apart from each other. You can fix this by installing filters, see section **4.22 Skipping Or Changing Coordinates – Filters** of the manual.